# 1px black line appearing down right side of thumbnails (theme snaps)

Tags: themes, thumbnails, images

For some reason on most of the thumbnails there is a black 1px line to the right of the image.

This looks to be a cropping issue or something but there is a 1px thick line on the right hand side of a lot of my thubnails.

I am unsure why this is as all the thumbnail images are the same size. You can see the page at http://192.185.117.216/~danielnolan/web/.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I think the image does not take all available space that it has, you can add a `width: 100%;` on the `.post-thumbnail img`. It solves the issue here.

Edit: You can see, by looking at the chrome dev tools (or firefox/IE) that the container does not have the save width as it children :

[image]
[image]